# How to properly import flatpickr on laravel mix

Tags: javascript, laravel, flatpickr

I want use daterange picker from flatpickr library on laravel but when i try to initiate it i got an error if `self.config.plugins[i] is not a function`. I have follow the instruction but still not find the solution.

Here my code to reproduce:

package.json file:

```
{
    .....
    .....
    "dependencies": {
        .....
        .....
        "flatpickr": "^4.6.3",
        .....
        .....
    }
}
```

bootstrap.js

```
require('flatpickr');

const $daterangePicker = $('[data-plugins="daterange-picker"]');

if ($daterangePicker.length > 0) {
  $daterangePicker.flatpickr({
    mode: 'range',
  });
}
```

Blade view:

```
<div class="form-group mr-2">
 <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm"
        data-plugins="daterange-picker" placeholder="2018-10-03 to 2018-10-10">
</div> <!-- end form-group mr-2 -->
```

Console log errors:

```
TypeError: self.config.plugins[i] is not a function
    at parseConfig (flatpickr.js:1977)
    at init (flatpickr.js:588)
    at FlatpickrInstance (flatpickr.js:2522)
    at _flatpickr (flatpickr.js:2541)
    at jQuery.fn.init.jQuery.fn.flatpickr (flatpickr.js:2592)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (kuhaku.js:22)
    at mightThrow (jquery.js:3762)
    at process (jquery.js:3830)
```

Comment: Make sure that you have only one jQuery being loaded into your page as a global or, better yet, use `require('flatpickr'); const $ = require('jquery'); $(...)`

Comment: i use default laravel configuration to load jquery `try {
  window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
  window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

  require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {
  //
}`

Comment: I don't know what your environment is, are you using webpack or something?

Comment: i use laravel mix and is like webpack..
i also try to integrate on fresh laravel app and still display error like that 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your `data-plugins` attribute. Change the name of it to almost anything else and it'll work fine.

In your bootstrap:

```
const $daterangePicker = $('[data-type="daterange-picker"]');

    if ($daterangePicker.length > 0) {
        $daterangePicker.flatpickr({
            mode: 'range',
        });
    }
```

In your blade template:

```
<div class="form-group mr-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm"
                   data-type="daterange-picker" placeholder="2018-10-03 to 2018-10-10">
        </div> <!-- end form-group mr-2 -->
```

Comment: Its.. work...:D
can u explain why its not work when i use data-plugins attribute?

Comment: The `data-plugins` attribute is used BY flatpickr to look for externally loaded plugins.  So it kept trying to load a configuration for a plugin which wasn't loaded (because it doesn't exist, as mode `range` is native to flatpickr.